# unable to remove border on button with css. please suggest any method after trying in chrome browser and ie browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Please open the below link in chrome browser
and try to remove the border without affecting the design.
The are blue buttons with border if you see in chrome or ie browsers.

http://web-chief.co.uk/podocare/?page_id=136

i tried various methods but still no progress.

Please don't mark this as duplicate question as i have tried all the soln available here with no result.

Comment: please include the relevant code in the question itself. Linking to a website isn't considered good practise as when the site is changed, the question becomes obsolete.

Comment: You are using image in that buttons. And if image(src="" or no src or src="validURL") is not present border will appear

Comment: There is an `img` inside the `a` which has no `src` specified. Hence the default blank image placeholder.

Comment: but it is generated via short code [button] in wordpress... so what should i do ?

Comment: In short codes, there will be some place where you can give url to image.

Comment: okay if you manually add a src with some valid url in image tag will it remove the border? i tried in firebug but no result.

Comment: Please run my snippet in my answer and check the difference

Comment: wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy to much inline styling going on!

Comment: it appears here right but it doesnot work on my source

Comment: If you're not setting an image, why are you using the image tag???

Comment: Yes, if ur not using img then remove it...your problem will be solved

Comment: thanks. i removed the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give value of src to img tag in order to work else border will appear.It means that `src=""` or `src` or `src="nonexistingURl.jpg"` is unable to find your image.

```html
<button>No border<img height="50" width="50" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRG38VK4-kYeMdF1fQ6RbhfDoUjbE8smcnFrvJrVg5n1xwP4tN"></button>

<button>Default border<img height="50" width="50" src="noValidUrl.jpg" alt="Image not found"></button>
```

In firefox, if src of img tag is invalid then it doesn't show any box which is behavior of browser.

In chrome- Box will be shown saying that there some image missing here.

**Solution**:
If you are not using img tag then remove it else give valid url to img tag using your wordpress.

Comment: it shows border. open my link in chrome and in the firebug locate the image tag and edit it there and paste your html. border still appears.

Comment: You have to give valid url or remove img tag from button. Please run the code snippet

Comment: You can accept the answer if you are satisfied with answer :D

Answer (score 0):

My guess: The border you see is applied by the browser to alert user that the image source is missing or empty. You cannot place img in html without specifing the image src , otherwise every browser will affect the design and show the frame.

Comment: it works fine in firefox but this issue is caused only in ie and chrome

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [Google Map Lightbox Popup wordpress plugin](http://www.wpfruits.com/downloads/wp-plugins/google-map-lightbox-popup-wordpress-plugin/#?custom=true&width=500&height=500)

As it is shown in their settings panel, if you check the checkbox to show a custom image instead of theirs you should include the image path. Without the image path it will generate the img tag without the src attribute just like in your case. So either insert a custom image (for example the blue box with the arrow) or you would have to rework the plugin files.

[image]

Comment: To hide the image just add .click_it{opacity: 0;} and it will work :)